# I know how to get the z-index, but is there a way to get the absolute Z on the page (the numeric, and never AUTO)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

Obtaining the z is as simple as:

```
$("#sample").css("z-index");
```

which is fine, but I want to check layers for their absolute z-index.

The issue here is that the z-index can return AUTO, but I want to know what the actual z-index is AT THAT SECOND in relation to all other layers on the page?

I was looking through Javascript to see if there was a way with

```
element.styles.zIndex;
```

but that didnt seem to work either.

Has anyone come to resolutions to this?  I was figuring since each browser builds the page differently, i might have to check and account for the different ways browsers would handle and store this information.

**EDIT:**   When i mean Absolute Z, i mean:  The page builds and every layer, is z-index: auto pretty much.  In reference to the page, what is the real z-index.  So, insead of auto, it would be a number.  It would be the number that corresponds to that layers ACTUAL z-index as that very instance.

Comment: You'll need to iterate over all absolutely positioned elements, get the zIndexes, then get the max - assuming that's what you mean by getting the 'absolute'

Comment: oh, no, i dont mean things with position absolute.  I mean, the page doesnt assign Z-Indices at all, so everything is auto.  How would i determine what the Z is of the item as a number, and not return: "auto"

Comment: For unpositioned elements, there is no z-index. The way they overlap is purely based on where they are in the DOM tree. So if that's what you need, you should count all the elements before the one you're interested in.

Comment: You mean Count right?   Well the other issue with that is siblings?  So should i look at ALL siblings before it in the dom tree as well?

Comment: Yes, but that is assuming the elements are non-positioned *or* they have equal computed values for `z-index`. Long story short, it's very complicated, and you cannot obtain this information from querying the `z-index` style.

Comment: @BoldClock i know it is very complicated, but it is something i want to do.  If it cannot be determined purely from the styles, do you know how it would work from the javascript/brower point of view?  I figure i can work to write it for 1 browser and expand it on an as-needed basis

Comment: I think you should question why you need this, as I'm almost certain there will be a better solution

Comment: Having a bunch of siblings on screen, i want to shift them forward and backwards for layering purposes.  The z-index isnt defined at all, so when the pages render, they are just AUTO.  or:  .zIndex() = 0.   I was thinking to just increment the z each time an object was created, so that way, the items would determine layering based on the order objects are created.

Comment: If they're all children of the same parent, AND you're only interested in those children (not in elements outside of the parent nor any grandchildren) AND none of them have a style of `position` then your z-index would simply be the node index in the parent. But if you are "layering" them, that means you'll be giving them `position` right?

Comment: Yes, they all have position: relative|absolute if that is what you are talking about.  They all have a coordinate system and dimensions in which they adhere to: Left, Top, Height, and Width... just no 30dimensional coordinates

Comment: In that case, they each have their own stacking order and they're not related. I'm not even sure if there are rules for those cases.

Answer (score 0):

> *I was figuring since each browser builds the page differently, i might have to check and account for the different ways browsers would handle and store this information.*

Yes. JqueryUI has tried to solve this with [.zIndex()](http://api.jqueryui.com/zIndex/):

> This method will start at the specified element and walk up the DOM until it finds an element that is positioned and has a z-index set. If no such element is found, then the method will return a value of 0. ...it is impossible to differentiate between an explicit value of 0 and no value in Internet Explorer.

Comment: I create elements and fire the draggable() property on them.  The issue is that, some things are layered in front, and others behind when moving things about.  I want to know what its exact positioning is in reference to other things created so i can manipulate with buttons like: "Move Forward"  or "Send to Back"  etc.  This index idea, when quickly implemented returns 0 for everything, which to me is wrong.  I figured since they are layered and move in front of each other, that there would be subtle differences in their Indices

Comment: In that case, just explicitly set a `z-index` when you create the elements. Then you can manipulate to your heart's content because everything will have a numeric value instead of `auto`.

Comment: That was a thought, as currently built and loaded pages add orders in a queue.  The preservance of Z is not in the styucture, other then the order at which they are "drawn" on screen which can be adjusted (to some extent).  The issue is, i wouldnt know where to start:  What should my baseline be, should im implement in increments of 100?  etc... All that other stuff starts to come into play, or if i should just increment by 1, and then i can shift z's as needed while pushing elements around the structure.

Comment: More clearly,  explicitly set _an incremented_ `z-index` when you create the elements.  You need to force a `z-index` so you can manipulate layers forward and back.

Comment: Ah, ok.  I was hoping to do something like no matter if it was auto or not, get its Z as a numeric and then adjust it in accordance to the other indices around it.